# Why isn't VS code recognizing my solidity code? my solidity files are not different colors or self correcting as if they are code

Tags: solidity, visual-studio-code

My .sol files are reading like a text file...no different colors or autofill happening.

- I'm using VS Code
- I've used several different solidity extensions but the text is not being recognized as code.
- I installed Solidity using my machines terminal.

I feel like I am missing something very basic here. Any ideas??

Comment: Which solidity plugin have you installed? Are they enabled?

Comment: - I have the suggested Solidity extension for Hardhat - Nomic Foundations
- yes it is enabled

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+Shift+P then press enter or select "Format Document With..." Is solidity an option on this list? If so, select it.

Answer (score 0):

This VSC extension helped me: "Solidity Language & Themes (only)"
The code became colorful